# Issues With JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs

I'm new to JAX-RS and having a number of issues (which oddly make me miss SOAP). Here is a snippet of my code. The getMergedPDFReport method should take a file and return a file after some processing. After which I would worry about the client

```
@GET
@Produces("application/pdf")
@Path("merge-service")
public Response getMergedPDFReport(@QueryParam(ApiParameters.WORD_DOCUMENT) File wordDocument,
                                   @QueryParam(ApiParameters.MERGE_FIELDS)Object[] fieldNames,
                                   @QueryParam(ApiParameters.MERGE_VALUES) Object [] fieldValues) {
    ResponseBuilder builder =null;
    try {
        File product = DocumentUtil.generatePDF(wordDocument, fieldNames, fieldValues);

        builder = Response.ok(product);
        builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\\\"report.pdf\\\"");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.build();
}
```

I get a warning on my server log that says "No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response". I can't seem to know why.
2. Am I using the @QueryParam annotation right? Should I be using it for types of File, and arrays? I saw a lot of debates online over @BeanParam, @MatrixParam and @QueryParam. Since I didn't know what the first two do, I decided to Keep It Simple.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if the warning you get is actually related to the code you've presented as you do not have a parameter of type `Response` in that method. Your general design has a couple of flaws IMO: Use HTTP POST rather than GET to upload files. GET is a safe and idempotent operation and therefore must not change a resources state. The URI invoked is often restricted by frameworks in length. If you pass encoded files as query parameter the length of the URI can become rather large and therefore increase the likelihood of rejections.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use queryParam for files. You must use a @Consumes with a multipart form.

Check this :
http://www.javatpoint.com/jax-rs-file-upload-example

Comment: The core issue is, that the OP is trying to send a file using `GET` method. While according to [RFC 7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) the semantics of a payload issued with a GET request are not specified, the spec discouragaes the use of GET bodies in order to stay backwards compatible with older version which may reject GET requests issuing bodies. Further, if the file is actually small it could be encoded using i.e. base64 and passed as query parameter, though this is not beautiful in any way